# Align ticklabels in matplotlib colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a colorbar with positive and negative values which are generated automatically (I am not setting them). Unfortunately the minus sign breaks the vertical alignment of the text. How can I align all the text in the ticklabels to the right or alternatively insert a space before my positive numbers to make it look good?

[image]

Comment: I don't know how I've missed this question so far, I've thoroughly searched for something similar multiple times. Seemingly such a simple and natural thing that we want to do... This needs more upvotes;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was just about to ask the same question, then finally found yours. So I'd like to add my own work-around.

At first I used the exact same solution [given by Rutger Kassies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19220562/5067311). However, when plotting in `ipython`, the same amount of shift in `x` position will give wildly different results when viewing a small window, or setting the figure to full screen.

I've eventually settled on setting the `pad` of the colorbar's tick labels. <strike>Borrowing</strike> Blatantly stealing the sample code of Rutger:

```
a = np.random.randn(10,10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

im = ax.imshow(a, interpolation='none')
cb = plt.colorbar(im)

ticklabs = cb.ax.get_yticklabels()
cb.ax.set_yticklabels(ticklabs,ha='right')
cb.ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(pad=45)  # your number may vary
```

This workaround seems to give a much more consistent result when using across various window sizes and aspects.

Here's 4 outputs to demonstrate what I mean: top row is the position shifting solution, bottom row is my padding solution. On the left are the default figure window sizes, the right side was `savefig`ged after popping the figure window to full screen:

[image: top row older solution, bottom row is mine]

Answer (score 5):

You can change the alignment of the text. It might be necessary to change the (x) position of the label a bit to prevent overlap with the colorbar itself.

```
a = np.random.randn(10,10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

im = ax.imshow(a, interpolation='none')
cb = plt.colorbar(im)

for t in cb.ax.get_yticklabels():
    t.set_horizontalalignment('right')   
    t.set_x(3.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I've found a slightly different solution that is a bit more robust to changing window sizes. I'm mainly leaving this comment to ask you to let me know if you've found some even better workarounds in the past 2 years.

Answer (score 3):

It's easiest to do this with the format option when creating your colorbar.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.random.randn(10,10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

im = ax.imshow(a, interpolation='none')

colorbar_format = '% 1.1f'
cb = plt.colorbar(im, format=colorbar_format)
```

So basically you use the Python "%" string format. https://pyformat.info/

If you know you have negatives note the extra space after % which will 'placehold' it for you, adding a space to positives and nothing to the negatives. You might need to play around with this to get it to fit your use case best. I've also noticed that if you aren't setting your own tick values:

```
cb = plt.colorbar(im, ticks=your_own_ticks, format=colorbar_format)
```

The number and distribution of ticks may change based on the format you use.

[image: Example of formatted strings in plot colorbar labels]

Comment: Note that this leads to typographically incorrect hyphens and not minuses in the labels. You probably have to enclose the format in dollar signs to trigger math rendering.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to tolerate a smaller negative sign, then this seems to work well for me.

```py
arr = np.random.randn(10,10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

im = ax.imshow(arr, interpolation=None)
cb =  plt.colorbar(im)

def format_func(x, pos):
    x = str(x)
    pad = '' if x.startswith('-') else ' '
    return '{}{}'.format(pad, x)

cb.ax.yaxis.major.formatter = mpl.ticker.FuncFormatter(format_func)
```

The docs for the Tick Locator and Formatter can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html)

My guess is that if you switch to a monospace font the results would be better. The main advantage is not having the manually set `pad` or `x` values.

I am not cool enough to embed images yet, so if you're interested in seeing the
output here it is as the [default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5oxs.png) size, and after [maximizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vWu4.png).